# Displaying more than 5columns in recycler view with horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using recycler view with a layout that consists of 4 text views but I want to display more than 5 columns in the layout with horizontal scroll view? Is it feasible and possible? If yes, can anyone share any link or code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Horizontal scroll view, set your RecylerView layoutManager as follows,

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager
       = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

In RecyclerView ,

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

In RecyclerView item layout,

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: I'm trying this but most of the time it doesn't scroll